# design for DB when needed to know lastest for something

Tags: mysql, database

let's say I have the following objects:

```
Site: 

idSite,
name
and other static data. 

Test:

idTest
idSite
name
and other static data.

Site Version:

idSiteVersion,
idSite
name of version


Test Result:

ןdTestResult
idSiteVersion, 
idTest,
timeEnded
```

for each site, there is a list of tests that are registered for him.

now I want to know for each `site version` the latest `testresults` for them, grouped by `idTest`.
and also those who are not tested, with null as value.(b)

I've implimented a DB for this.

but I have trouble to get the query I've listed (b) , it takes a considerbly long time.

I'm thinking of remodeling it. any advices will help

the new one will consist of a table `LATEST` that will act as a cache,
so I'll use triggers on insert to update the right row,
and will select from it.

is that right?
should I remodel this?

query:

```
select `tr1`.`id` AS `id`,
`dsv`.`idSite_id` AS `idSite`,
`tr1`.`idSiteVersion_id` AS `idSiteVersion`,
`tr1`.`idTest_id` AS `idTest`,
`tr1`.`result` AS `result`,
`tr1`.`timeStarted` AS `timeStarted`,
 from 
`dash`.`testresult` `tr1` 
join `dash`.`siteversion` `dsv` on `dsv`.`id` = `tr1`.`idSiteVersion_id`
join `dash`.`test` `dtest` on `dtest`.`id` = `tr1`.`idTest_id` 
where `dtest`.`ignored` = 0 and `tr1`.`timeEnd` = 
( select max(`tr2`.`timeEnd`) from `dash`.`testresult` `tr2` 
    where 
       ((`tr2`.`idTest_id` = `tr1`.`idTest_id`) and 
       (`tr2`.`idSiteVersion_id` = `tr1`.`idSiteVersion_id`) and 
       (`tr2`.`timeEnd` is not null)))
```

Comment: Remove idSite from TestResult becouse you can get it through the Test.

Comment: It would help if you posted your query.  If you have a slow query, generally the first thing to do is profile it to verify that it is using the correct indices, etc.

Comment: @Jason, just `show profile` ?

Comment: @shevski show us the query. If it is taking a considerable amount of time it most likely could be optimized without the need of a restructure.

Comment: @MatthewCox it takes more than a few seconds, I'll post it when in work

Comment: @shevski what column in `Test` where you wanting to group by?

Comment: @MatthewCox, I've added the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```sql
SELECT
  tr1.id AS id,
  dsv.idSite_id AS idSite,
  tr1.idSiteVersion_id AS idSiteVersion,
  tr1.idTest_id AS idTest,
  tr1.result AS result,
  tr1.timeStarted AS timeStarted,
FROM 
  dash.testresult AS tr1 
  NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT idTest_id, idSiteVersion_id, MAX(timeEnd) AS timeEnd
    FROM dash.testresult
    WHERE timeEnd IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY idTest_id, idSiteVersion_id
  ) AS tr2
  JOIN dash.siteversion AS dsv
    ON dsv.id = tr1.idSiteVersion_id
  JOIN dash.test AS dtest
    ON dtest.id = tr1.idTest_id AND dtest.ignored = 0
```

Also, you definitely want to create an index on `dash.testresult (idTest_id, idSiteVersion_id, timeEnd)` if you don't already have one.

Comment: the `AND` the the end of the query is meant to be `WHERE`?

Comment: You can use `WHERE dtest.ignored = 0` too, but I made it part of the join condition since it seemed nicer to me like that.  It shouldn't make any difference either way here.

Comment: that query really reduced runtime